# How to print diagrams that are too large for a single page readably?

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design, export, diagram, chart-design

I made a big flowchart of an app. The app has many menus and pages, so it became a very big file. The dimensions of the diagram are:

Width: 272,21 cm / 17147 px
Height: 91,37 cm / 5756 px

This is much bigger than an A3 or A4. How can I make it readable across several pages? I want to send it as a pdf to my boss.

Comment: Hi Nami92, Welcome to GD.SE! So what exactly is your issue? Are you worried that the document is too big and that makes it hard to read or are you worried the file is too big? Or are you just wondering if there is a better way of presenting the flow chart?

Comment: I'm wondering what is the best way to present my flowchart, All the small text has to be readable. thanks. @AndrewH

Comment: if you send a PDF it will be readable when your boss zooms in, or am I missing something? Does it need to be printed?

Comment: If this needs to be printed you need to make that clear in your question, if not theres no issue, you can zoom in on a PDF as much as you want (assuming it's vector, and it should be, the text at the very least).

Answer (score 1):

Exporting as a PDF will make it useful to the largest audience. The file size is small, easy to zoom in, and every computer or device can display a PDF file.

Because these things change often, a printed version may be quickly out-of-date. If you do want to print it, many print shops have large-format printers that can easily print on paper this large, it's basically a banner.